# Xcode Swift - WKWebView implementation

Tags: swift, xcode, wkwebview

I am currently trying to implement a simple `WKWebView` in a Navigation Page in Xcode using Swift, however, as soon as I switch to the dedicated page the app crashes and throws the following exception:

> 2021-01-12 16:24:40.981110+0100 SmartMirror[2078:1089320] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[WKWebView view]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x11380c400'

I'm also using an activity indicator, which is supposed to show until the page is loaded. This is my code: `ThirdViewController.swift`

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ThirdViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet var webView: WKWebView!
    @IBOutlet var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!
    
    override func loadView() {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        let url = URL(string: "http://192.168.178.34:8080/")
        let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        webView.load(request)
        webView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(WKWebView.isLoading), options: .new, context: nil)
    }

    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        
        if keyPath == "loading" {
            
            if webView.isLoading {
                activityIndicator.startAnimating()
                activityIndicator.isHidden = false
            }else {
                activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                activityIndicator.isHidden = true
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

And this is my storyboard, with each page having its own view:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFFlH.jpg

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Sincerely,
Lukas

Comment: I tested your code and I have a `nil` value on the `activityIndicator` in the `else` statement. But it's different error that you wrote. If I comment those lines it works fine with another `url`.

Comment: I tried the same thing with "https://google.com" and I get the same error as before. I feel like it has to do with my ViewController, but I couldn't say. Did you use one page only?

Comment: I tested in `TabController` with two `ViewControllers`. In the second one I added the `webView`. Try without `loadView()` function and it should work as well.

Comment: Thanks for your proposed edit btw.! I also tried that, however, it still doesn't work. It only loads the third page if I get rid of the webView and the activityIndicator.

Comment: That's the thing, even if I comment out everything and only leave the WebView and the ActivityIndicator in the storyboard, the app crashes as soon as I switch to page three.

Comment: I am going to see if I can get it running in a simplified version and expand on that if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now completely recreated the whole app and it's working now. It seems something went wrong when I created the ViewControllers for the three pages. I have also kept the original ViewController this time.

This is the code I've used after all: `ThirdViewController.swift`

```
//
//  ThirdViewController.swift
//  SmartMirror
//

import UIKit
import WebKit

class ThirdViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet var webView: WKWebView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        let url = URL(string: "http://192.168.178.34:8080/")
        let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        webView.load(request)
    }
    
}
```

**Thanks to everyone that helped me!**

Comment: You can mark your own answer as the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[WKWebView view]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

As you probably know, this is because somebody is sending a `-view` message to your web view, which doesn't have a method by that name. `UIViewController` has such a method, though, so it's a good guess that somewhere in your app, your web view is being mistaken for a view controller. I don't see that happening in the code you posted, and it's hard to tell anything from just an image of a storyboard.

The way you can find the issue is to look at the stack trace when the error occurs. Find the thread where the exception is thrown, and then look down the stack for the one where the `-view` is called. That should show you what method is making the call. If the call isn't in your code, then look at the class involved... you should be able to at least get some clues as to what type of object is calling `-view`, and you can look at your code for the place where you configure that object.

Comment: This is what I could find:
`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIViewController 0x100d0ebf0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key activityIndicator.'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException`

Comment: That's a different error. Could be the same underlying cause, but it's a different exception. You need to run your app in the debugger and add a breakpoint for all exceptions so that execution stops when an exception is thrown.